# Combine for iterators to avoid duplicates in python

Tags: python, for-loop, duplicates

I have 2 `for` loops that work well. The problem is that I want to combine them in order to avoid to append duplicates in my `data2` dataframe. In other words, I want the `for value in Dic["synonyms.0"].values:` loop to happen only when no there is no `value in line :` from the preceding `for` iteration.

Here is my code:

```
for value in Dic["label"].values:
                if (value != None) :
                    if value in line :
                        data2.append([value, line.count(value), len(value),dosage])
for value in Dic["synonyms.0"].values:
                if (value != None) :
                    if value in line :
                        data2.append([value, line.count(value), len(value),dosage])
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, do you just need to assign a boolean before the first for loop that becomes false if entering the if statement (which then stops the second for loop running)?

Comment: I want the second loop to happen only when no value has been found in `if value in line :` in the first loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a boolean value that determines how the first iteration went

```
found_value = False
for value in Dic["label"].values:
    if (value != None) :
        if value in line :
            data2.append([value, line.count(value), len(value),dosage])
            found_value = True
if not found_value:
    for value in Dic["synonyms.0"].values:
        if (value != None) :
            if value in line :
                data2.append([value, line.count(value), len(value),dosage])
```

As pointed out in the comments, if you're not making use of `break` in your first for loop, this can replace the boolean

```
for value in Dic["label"].values:
    if (value != None) :
        if value in line :
            data2.append([value, line.count(value), len(value),dosage])
            break
else:
    for value in Dic["synonyms.0"].values:
        if (value != None) :
            if value in line :
                data2.append([value, line.count(value), len(value),dosage])
```

Comment: How about `for else` though :o

Comment: This is a perfect situation for `for else`: instead of the `found_value` flag you just `break` and then the `else` clause won't do the second iteration

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper - Good point, you could but given the odd indentation in the op's question i wouldn't want to limit the usage of `break`

Comment: I can also delete the `found_value = False` line when I use `break` and `else`?

Comment: @marou95thebest - Yes